# Git - assertion failed on push to subtree repository

Tags: git, blob, push, git-subtree, subtree

My situation is simple - I have a parent repository with a subtree nested in a subdirectory. Originally, these were two separate repos (i.e. I did not use the subtree split tool). I created the subtree on machine #1 like so:

```
git subtree add --prefix [my prefix] [repo url] trunk --squash
```

I then pushed to the parent repository remote with no issues. Then I checked out the parent repo on machine #2 (again no problems so far). Still within the parent repo, I made a change to a file inside of the subtree directory, committed from the root of the parent project, and pushed to the parent.

At this point I wanted to also push the change to the subtree's repository, so I tried running:

```
git subtree push --prefix [my prefix] [repo url] trunk
```

After a few minutes of it checking commits, it resulted in an error:

```
fatal: assertion failed: test blob = tree -o blob = commit
```

I can't find anything online explaining why this might be happening, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You was probably having file for both repos in your commit, try again with a clean commit